# write a test class for apex class

Tags: apex

I am new to apex, I'm interested in writing a test class for the following controller, but not sure where to begin. Here is my apex class code.

```
public class tree {
   public Account acct{get;set;}  
    //private final Account acct;
    public ApexPages.StandardController stdController {get;set;}
    public tree(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        stdController.addFields(new String[]{'Id','Tete_de_groupe__c'});
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
       // this.stdController = stdController;
       }
    public List<Account> listOfAccount(){
        List<Account> acctList;
        if (acct.Tete_de_groupe__c == null){
        acctList = [SELECT Name,Parent.Name,id,Code_NAF__c ,Industry ,RecordType.Name,Adresse_Agence__c, Tete_de_groupe__c,Statut__c 
                                 FROM Account
                                 where id = :this.acct.id or Tete_de_groupe__c = :this.acct.id ];}
        else {
        acctList = [Select Name,Parent.Name,id,Tete_de_groupe__c,Statut__c
                          from Account
                          where id = :this.acct.Tete_de_groupe__c or Tete_de_groupe__c = :this.acct.Tete_de_groupe__c];}
            return acctList;
    }
    Public String getaccountdata(){
        String datastr1 = '';
        String datastr2 = '';
        String datastr = '';
        List<Account> lstOfAcc =listOfAccount(); 
        for (integer i=0;i<lstOfAcc.size();i++){
     if (lstOfAcc[i].Parent.Name == null){
        datastr1 = datastr1 + '{"name": "';
        datastr1+= lstOfAcc[i].Name;
        datastr1+= '","parent": ';
        datastr1+= lstOfAcc[i].Parent.Name;
        datastr1+= ',"accountid": "';
        datastr1+= lstOfAcc[i].id;
        datastr1+= '","Statut__c": "';
        datastr1+= lstOfAcc[i].Statut__c;
        datastr1+='" }';
    }
     else{
       datastr2 = datastr2 + '{"name": "';
        datastr2+= lstOfAcc[i].Name;
        datastr2+= '","parent": "';
        datastr2+= lstOfAcc[i].Parent.Name;
        datastr2+= '","accountid": "';
        datastr2+= lstOfAcc[i].id;
        datastr2+= '","Statut__c": "';
        datastr2+= lstOfAcc[i].Statut__c;

        datastr2+='" },';  
     }
    }
    if(datastr2 == ''){datastr = '[' + datastr1 + ']';}
    else {
        datastr2 = datastr2.substring(0,datastr2.length()-1);
        datastr = '[' + datastr1 +','+ datastr2 + ']'; }
    return datastr;
    }
}
```

I want to create test class. Guys need help if some one can tell me about test class of this apex class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AParise pointed out the consideration. What you need to do in your test class, step by step:

- Insert some account objects into the database (the test runs doesn't see any data by default, and that's OK)
- Keep the ID from the first account and use it for `Tete_de_groupe__c` for the others.

Call the function, roughly like this:

```
   Account mainAccount = populateTestAccounts(); // Helper function
   Tree t = new Tree();
   t.setAcct(mainAccount);
   String result = t.getaccountdata();
   assert(....);
```

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

For unit tests regarding classes like the one you posted, the easiest way is to think about expected results given a code path. For each test method, ask yourself: "Given this set of data, when I invoke this method, I expect this to occur".

Let's walk through your "getaccountdata" method.
"Given this set of data..." - What data does this method require for proper execution? Without diving too deep into your logic, this probably means inserting some Account sObjects.

"When I invoke this method..." - the "getaccountdata" method is being invoked.

"I expect this to occur..." - This is where your assertions come into play. You created the Account sObjects with specific values, so verify that these values propagated into your method return value.

Comment: thank you @AParise for your response, i don't know how to call the method getaccountdata() in my class test could you help me please ??